# Is it possible to customize JVM's c1 or c2 JIT compiler or the profiler used by the JIT compiler?

Tags: jvm, jit

Is customizing JIT a viable alternative to some of the JNI use-cases?

Edit:
For the purpose of improving performance via custom hardware such as GPU or FPGA.  I am aware of Project Sumatra but I believe it is GPU focus and it is no longer active.  Optimization via JNI requires explicit specification at the source, while things like intrinsic in JIT (may be a more custom and complex version of intrinsic) can make optimization a bit more automatic?

Comment: Not yet. There are plans to introduce such a feature in Java 9, see [JEP 243: Java-Level JVM Compiler Interface](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/243), however, I’m not sure whether this will be a viable alternative to JNI. That would require to replicate the work of whatever compiler you normally would use for the native code. So there might be use cases where this could replace former JNI usages, but it won’t be an alternative in general.

Comment: what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Wow, -1?  Anyway, made an edit to give more context.  Thanks @Holger for pointing out JEP243.  That looks interesting.

Comment: offloading to other compute units would more than just JITing. yes, there's code that needs to be compiled for those targets. but you also need to arrange for that code to be executed and if they don't have unified memory also for the data to be moved there and then await completion

Comment: In addition to the JEP 243 mentioned above, I suggest you take a look at the [Project Panama](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/) and its key JEP [Foreign Function Interface](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/191).